# How to get rid of the “scanning for btrfs file systems” at start-up?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, btrfs

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10, I get a message "scanning for btrfs file systems" at starting-up. I don't have any BTRFS filesystem. It delays the booting for about 15 seconds.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: I uninstalled btrfs to find out, that the scan for btrfs is not the reason for the delay. after removing btrfs it still hangs but one line earlyer at `Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount`

Comment: There is also btrfs superblock scanning in every partition in libblkid - https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid/src/superblocks/btrfs.c#L62 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libblkid/src/superblocks/btrfs.c

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `btrfs-tools` package adds an action to the initramfs to load the btrfs module. If you purge that package (`sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools`), followed by an `update-initramfs -ukall` if the uninstallation doesn't do it already, that should go away (though I've not tested it). If it doesn't, you can always blacklist the `brtfs` module in `/etc/modprobe.d`.

Comment: Doing this on Ubuntu server 16.04 apt gives me "The following packages will be REMOVED: btrfs-tools* ubuntu-server*". Hmm, I'd like to keep the server though...

Comment: @elomage, `ubuntu-server` is just a _meta-package_ that is used to pull packages typically found on server-style installations as dependencies. By removing it (provided no other package are removed as a result), you're not removing any software.

Comment: Thanks. Improved my elementary Juno startup times.

Answer (score 21):

On Ubuntu 18.04 you can uninstall btrfs-support with

```
apt purge btrfs-progs
```

But that probably wouldn't save you much boot time. On my system the reason was, that I don't have a swap partition but on boot it is searched for such for about 30 seconds (while displaying the btrfs-scan).

#### remove the swap check

- open `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
- replace `RESUME=UUID=xxx` with `RESUME=none`
- issue `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- reboot your system

(create the file if it does not exist and just add `RESUME=none` in it)

*source:* https://askubuntu.com/a/1034952/34298

Comment: This is the actual issue! The swap search is hidden after btrfs seek. Thanks you very so much!

Answer (score 5):

Btrfs isn’t too much stable to be used as deafult file-system. Most Linux distributions, probable all, are still using ext4 as primary file-system. So, you can completely remove it from your computer. Try the given command:

```
sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools
```

This command will remove btrfs-tools from your computer. You may need to wait some minutes to complete the process. Your initramfs should be updated automatically but if not happen, do it by this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -ukall
```

Then make a grub update:

```
sudo update-grub
```

All is well. Now make a restart. Hope your Ubuntu will start successfully this time.

Reference: http://www.ugcoder.com/disable-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-in-ubuntu/

Let me know if you have some questions still.

Comment: The package is not installed on my system. So i tried `echo "blacklist btrfs">>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` But no effect. still scanning for btrfs on boot

Answer (score 4):

I saw this as well on 18.04 during boot. Since

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/btrfs
```

calls for the scan, you can workaround this issue by dealing with that file. Since I wasn't using btrfs regularly, I purged the file through

```
sudo apt purge btrfs-progs
```

Comment: To get rid of that message, you need to do `sudo update-initramfs -ukall` as well. But still, that doesn't help much, the boot process then hangs at the step before saying `Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount`

Answer (score 2):

**Circa 2021**

At least with server versions of ubuntu `btrfs-tools` is not loaded by default and thus this unwanted scan is not an issue.  The issue arises when you install a distro that has tools which have `btrfs-tools` as a dependency like the popular `timeshift` which is included with mint. That creates the issue.  If you can live without `timeshift` then just remove `btrfs-tools` per other posts and you should be good to go (it will remove `timeshift` and update initramfs automatically).

BUT if you are like me use `qt-fsarchiver` or need `timeshift` then you can't just remove btrfs-tools as it is a dependency of both.  If you remove it you will remove them.  :(.

So this is what I did.

```
sudo modprobe -r btrfs
echo blacklist btrfs | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-btrfs.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

now reboot and watch to see if the btrfs scan was disabled.

Comment: That's similar to what I did, technically, after updating the initramfs, it's also possible to delete the blacklist file, and it'll allow using btrfs after the boot has finished.

Comment: If the kernel gets updated then initramfs will get rebuilt and if you remove the blacklist I guessing it will end up including the module again.  Unless there is  reason to I'd leave the blacklist.  If you indeed have a btrfs partition on the machine this whole issue is moot.  The scan should complete quickly and continue to boot so no reason to blacklist it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the btrfs kernel module that does the [scanning](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Device_scanning) (for filesystems scanning multiple devices).

I have not found an indication that this is configurable, so your only options seems to be removing that module from your kernel (`modprobe -r btrfs`) assuming your kernel supports that.

Comment: I tried, but it seems like this has no effect on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -2):

The script which starts the search looks for the existence of btrfs.
Simply renaming the executable `/sbin/btrfs` to p.e `/sbin/btrfs.save` (as `sudo`) will eliminate the search , gaining some 10-20 seconds in the boot-process!

Comment: it is not recommended to just delete system files.  better uninstall the btrfs too with `apt purge btrfs-tools`