# Long boot: BTRFS, swap space, and LVM

Tags: boot, lvm, swap, boot-loader, btrfs

I'm running into an issue where my computer hangs for close to 30 seconds on "scanning for btrfs file systems" during boot. I don't have any btrfs filesystems. I tried removing btrfs-tools and updating grub as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78535/how-to-get-rid-of-the-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-at-start-up). However, that didn't change anything.* The second answer in that link says that the culprit is really a scan for a swap partition. My computer has an SSD with Linux on an LVM, and the LVM is composed of a root block and a swap block. If the problem is the search for a swap partition and I disable the swap check, will the swap block still be available to deal with running out of memory and save my computer from crashing?

*Further complicating things, I have an issue with grub-update not updating the timeout as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123290/grub-timeout-in-etc-default-grub-not-changing-the-wait-time-with-lvm). It might be that grub-update isn't removing the btrfs check either; but it seems unlikely, as I was able to use grub-update to remove the splash screen and show the boot process text in the first place.